# NHibernate simple transaction takes at least 10 secs

Tags: .net, wpf, hibernate, nhibernate, sql-server-ce

I m using NHibernate and SqlCe database on wpf application. 
I create a parent row and add  about 10K records of childs on the parent row.
After than any simple transaction like inserting a single row on any table takes at least 10 seconrds.

When i restart the application and load the parent row and 10K child row, any any transaction is fast as normal.

What could be the cause?

### Trial class

```
public class Trial : JobsBase, INotifyPropertyChanged, ISoftDelete, IUniqueName, IDataErrorInfo, IFilter
{
    private int newrows;
    private int rows;
    private string name;
    private int cols;
    private int newcols;
    private string description;


    public Trial()
    {
        TrialId = new Guid();

    }

    public virtual Guid TrialId { get;  set; }

    public virtual string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {

            if (name == value) return;
            name = value;
            FirePropertyChangedEvent("Name");
        }
    }
    public virtual int Rows
    {
        get
        {
            return rows;
        }
        set
        {

            newrows = value;
            if (newrows * cols > 10000) { return; }
            if (rows == value) return;
            BuildCells(rows, cols, value, cols);
            rows = value;
            FirePropertyChangedEvent("Rows");
        }
    }
    public virtual int Cols
    {
        get
        {

            return cols;
        }
        set
        {
            newcols = value;
            if (newcols * rows > 10000) { return; }
            if (value == cols) return;
            BuildCells(rows, cols, rows, value);
            cols = value;
            FirePropertyChangedEvent("Cols");
        }
    }








    public virtual string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return description;
        }
        set
        {
            if (description == value) return;
            description = value;
            FirePropertyChangedEvent("Description");
        }
    }







    public virtual void CleanUpRows(int oldrows, int newrows)
    {
        for (int r = newrows; r < oldrows; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            {
                //cell to delete
                var delCell = new Cell() { X = c, Y = r };
                int index;
                if ((index = cells.IndexOf(delCell)) > -1)
                {
                    cells.RemoveAt(index);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public virtual void CleanUpColumns(int oldcols, int newcols)
    {
        for (int c = newcols; c < oldcols; c++)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
            {
                //cell to delete
                var delCell = new Cell() { X = c, Y = r };
                int index;
                if ((index = cells.IndexOf(delCell)) > -1)
                {
                    cells.RemoveAt(index);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public virtual void BuildCells(int oldrows, int oldcols, int newrows, int newcols)
    {

        //remove cells if rows cols size decreases
        if (oldrows > newrows) CleanUpRows(oldrows, newrows);
        if (oldcols > newcols) CleanUpColumns(oldcols, newcols);
        Debug.WriteLine("build cells: " +DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() );
        for (int i = 0; i < newcols; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < newrows; j++)
            {
                AddCell(new Cell { X = i, Y = j, Active = true });
            }
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("end build cells: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

    }
    private IList<Cell> cells = new List<Cell>();


    public virtual IList<Cell> Cells
    {
        get { return cells; }
        set { cells = value; }
    }

    public virtual void AddCell(Cell cell)
    {

        if (!HasCell(cell))
        {
            cell.Trial = this;
            cells.Add(cell);
        }
    }
    public virtual void RemoveCell(Cell cell)
    {
        cells.Remove(cell);
    }
    public virtual bool HasCell(Cell cell)
    {
        return cells.Contains(cell);
    }
    public virtual bool HasCell(int x, int y)
    {
        return HasCell(new Cell() { X = x, Y = y });
    }
    public virtual Cell SetCellActive(int x, int y, bool active)
    {
        int i = Cells.IndexOf(new Cell() { X = x, Y = y });
        Cells[i].Active = active;
        FireCellChanged(new CellEventArgs() { X = x, Y = y });
        return Cells[i];

    }
    public virtual Cell GetCell(int x, int y)
    {
        int i = Cells.IndexOf(new Cell() { X = x, Y = y });
        return i >= 0 ? Cells[i] : null;
    }


    public virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public virtual event EventHandler<CellEventArgs> CellChanged;

    private void FireCellChanged(CellEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<CellEventArgs> changed = CellChanged;
        if (changed != null) changed(this, e);
    }

    private void FirePropertyChangedEvent(string propertName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertName));
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return TrialId.ToString();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (this == obj) return true;

        var other = obj as Trial;
        if (other == null) return false;

        return TrialId.Equals(other.TrialId);

    }




    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return TrialId.GetHashCode();
    }

    public virtual string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string result = null;
            if (columnName == "Cols" || columnName == "Rows")
            {
                if (this.newcols * this.newrows > 10000)
                {
                    result = "No of cells must not exceed 10000";
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    public virtual string Error
    {
        get { return null; }
    }


    }

}
public class CellEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

### Cell

```
 public class Cell : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Cell()
        {
            CellId = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
        public virtual Guid CellId { get; set; }
        public virtual int MagazinNumber { get; set; } 
        public virtual int X { get; set; }
        public virtual int Y { get; set; }
        public virtual Trial Trial { get; set; }
        public virtual bool Active { get; set; }

        public virtual string CustomId { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return CellId.ToString();
        }

        public virtual bool EqualsById { get; set; }
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (this == obj) return true;

            var other = obj as Cell;
            if (other == null) return false;
            return other.EqualsById ? CellId.Equals(other.CellId) : X.Equals(other.X) && Y.Equals(other.Y);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return CellId.GetHashCode();
        }

        private IDictionary<string, float> _datalist;
        public virtual IDictionary<string, float> Datalist
        {
            get
            {
                if(_datalist==null)
                {
                    _datalist= new Dictionary<string, float>();
                    if (data != null)
                    {
                        var document = new XmlDocument();
                        document.LoadXml(data);
                        foreach (XmlNode childNode in document.FirstChild.ChildNodes)
                        {
                            if (childNode.Attributes == null) continue;

                            string key = childNode.Attributes["key"].Value;
                            float val = float.Parse(childNode.Attributes["value"].Value);
                            SetExtraField(key, val);
                        }
                    }

                }
                return _datalist;
            }

        }

        private void SetExtraField(string key, float value)
        {
            if (Datalist.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                Datalist[key] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                Datalist.Add(key, value);
            }
        }

        private float? GetExtraField(string key)
        {
            float value;
            return Datalist.TryGetValue(key, out value) ? (float?)value : null;
        }

        private int? GetExtraFieldInt(string key)
        {
            float value;
            return Datalist.TryGetValue(key, out value) ? (int?)value : null;
        }
        private string data;
        public virtual string Data
        {
            get
            {
                string xml = @"<datas>";
                foreach (var f in Datalist)
                {
                    xml += string.Format("<data key='{0}' value='{1}' />", f.Key, f.Value);
                }
                xml += "</datas>";
                return xml;
            }
            set
            {
                data = value;
            }
        }
```

---

### add trial to db

var trial = new Trial { "tset1" };

```
        trial.Rows = 10;
        trial.Cols = 1000;



        trial.Deleted = false;
        trial.BuildCells(10, 1000, 10, 1000);
        TrialDAO.Instance().Add(trial);
```

Comment: Provide some code. Are you closing session after you are finished?

Comment: Do you have any methods iterating over a collection child objects? If you do iterate over the children, even just to find a count of children using something like linq will cause all 10,000 children to be loaded. Without your code it is hard to know exactly what's going on.

Comment: Use stateless session to bulk insert. then close session and create normal session to insert single row, Do you still get the same problem?

Comment: @rafal no session closing. A single session is used through out the application.

Comment: @rafal
After adding trial to db every simple transaction takes too long time. (about 10 secs).

Comment: @JackHughes please check the code.

Comment: @Rippo can stateless session save collection of childs if update on parent object?

Answer (score 3):

So there it is.

Single session through the application lifetime is your cause. See nhibernate documentation on how to manage sessions.

See [NHibernate session management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150207/nhibernate-session-management) and [How to scope NHibernate sessions and transactions in a WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253025/how-to-scope-nhibernate-sessions-and-transactions-in-a-wpf-application).

From [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx):

> A common bad practice with NHibernate desktop applications is to have a single global session for the entire application. It is a problem for many reasons, ...

Comment: I must use the single session because I store the already loaded lists on the cache. 
Example of DAO
 public IList<T> GetAll()
        {
            if (!allRetrieved)
            {
                cache.Clear();
                var example = new T();
               
                    foreach (var item in dataprovider.GetAll())
                    {
                        cache.Add(item);
                    }
                
                allRetrieved = true;
            }
            return cache;
        }